# Cannot read property 'property_name' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is my code right now: https://jsfiddle.net/5phq111c/5/

Html Part

```
<tbody v-for="row in rows" :key="row.product_id">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select @change="selected" v-model="row.product_id" class="form-control" name="product_id" id="product_id">
                <option value="">Select Product</option>
                <option v-for="item in items" :value="item.id" v-text="item.product_name"></option>
            </select>                                           
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea type="text" v-model="product.product_details" name="product_details" id="product_details" class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="Product Details">
            </textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input v-model.number="product.product_sellPrice" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="rate" id="rate" placeholder="Rate">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Vue JS Part

```
export default {    
    data() {
        return {
            rows: [{
                product_id: '',
                product_details: '',
                product_sellPrice: '',      

            }],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addrow: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.rows.push({
            product_id: '',
            product_details: '',
            product_sellPrice: '',
        });
    },
    selected(e) {
        var id = this.row.product_id;
        console.log(id);
        axios.get('/estimate/product/' + id)
        .then((response)=>{
            this.product = '';
            this.product = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }); 
    }
}
```

I want to get the selected product_id and send an axios request to get the values of the the selected product. I have bind the product_id with the row. I am getting the selected value in the rows object but when I am sending the request by row.product_id i am getting the error can't read property 'product_id' of undefined. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't define a `row` data property, but a `rows` data property array. Calling the `selected` method from inside a `v-for` loop will not automatically assign `this.row` a value.

If you want the `product_id` of the selected row in the `selected` method, pass it in the template via `@change="selected(row.product_id)"`.

Then just reference that parameter in your `selected` method:

```
selected(id){
  console.log(id);
  axios.get('/estimate/product/' + id)
  ...
}
```

Comment: Well It is working but if I a add a new row, the new row is filled with the previous row data and changing a single is changing all other rows data

Comment: That's a separate issue and I'd think it's because you're pushing an object with `product_id` equal to an empty string and this is what is getting bound as the `:key` for each of the elements rendered by the `v-for`. But since all of the keys are the same value, the elements are rendered with the data from the first instance with that key. You need to provide and *unique* and *unchanging* value for the `key` attribute.

Comment: In that case how can I implement an unique key here?So that I can select every row with that key and find the values. "rows[0].quantity" like this.

Comment: Add a `row_id` property and assign it a unique id when you add a row  (you could do that by incrementing a counter `row_id: this.counter++`). Then use `row_id` as the `key` instead of `product_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to declare `rows` as an array with exactly one object in it:

```
    data() {
        return {
            rows: [{
                product_id: '',
                product_details: '',
                product_sellPrice: '',
            }],
```

But you try to access it just like a regular object:

```
var id = this.row.product_id;
```

In addition, you declare it as `rows`, but access it as `row` (missing plural `s`).

To get it running, first decide whether you want to name it `rows` or `row` and adapt the usage accordingly. Second, decide if `rows` must be an array (should it hold multiple objects?) or not.

If it should be an array, you probably want to access it like this:

```
var id = this.rows[0].product_id;
```

If it should not be an array, declare it like this:

```
    data() {
        return {
            rows: {
                product_id: '',
                product_details: '',
                product_sellPrice: '',      
            },
```

Comment: It will be an array. I will push more object by like this
this.rows.push({
        product_id: '',
     product_details: '',
     product_sellPrice: '',
       });
So what will be the way to declare var id = this.rows[?].product_id;?